Copy Notebook folder with Databricks Asset Bundles
I have a folder with python files and Databricks notebooks. Currently, I use a CI/CD Pipeline which uses REST calls to clone those files to a Databricks Workspace. I was considering to replace that with databricks asset bundles to get rid of my native implementation as the docu states:

Bundles make it possible to describe Databricks resources such as
jobs, pipelines, and notebooks as source files

Assume, I have a folder in git that looks like the following:
resources
- *.py
databricks.yml

I simply want a asset bundle that takes everything of the resource folder and copies it to a folder in my databricks workspace.
I tried the following setup in databricks.yml
  include:
  - resources/*
  targets:
    dev:
      workspace:
        host: https://adb***.net
        root_path: ~/DATABRICKS_BUNDLES
        notebooks_path: /Workspace/test

However, I always get an error

Error: failed to load /agent/_work/1/s/xxxx/notebook.py: :0:0: expected a map, found a invalid

When I remove the *.py from resources, it runs but nothing is copied.

According to the documentation, the include is only for configuration files, hence only .yml files. The error you are having is because the CLI is concatening all the files specified in the include paths and since you specified python files in it, it fails.
Databricks Asset Bundles relies heavily on the .gitignore to sync the folders and files between local and workspace. If your files are not ignored by the .gitignore, you should be able to find them on your root_path.
By default it should be something like :
Workspace > Users > your_username > .bundle > bundle_name > target_name

